# Does declaring many identical anonymous classes waste memory in java?

Tags: java

I recently ran across the following snippet in an existing codebase I'm working on and added the comment you see there.  I know this particular piece of code can be rewritten to be cleaner, but I just wonder if my analysis is correct.

Will java create a new class declaration and store it in perm gen space for every call of this method, or will it know to reuse an existing declaration?

```
protected List<Object> extractParams(HibernateObjectColumn column, String stringVal) {
    // FIXME: could be creating a *lot* of anonymous classes which wastes perm-gen space right?
    return new ArrayList<Object>() {
        {
            add("");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: But maybe using an inner class rather than a static nested class wastes a little memory for the outer$this pointer (in case that is not needed). That would be heap memory, though.

Comment: Duplicate code clutters your code and makes it harder to maintain, that's should be more of a worry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The class will only be compiled once (at compile time).  The compiler extracts a class (named something like `MyOuterClass$1`) and uses it.  It will create multiple instances, of course, but they will all be of the same class.  You can see that when you compile the `.java` file and look at the `.class` files generated - there will be one for the inner anonymous class.

Answer (score 5):

No, that creates many instances of *one* single class. To test, put this within your anonymous class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName();
}
```

Then call `toString()` on various instances of the anonymous class. You'll see they all return the same class name.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct.

However:

- If that pattern is repeated a number of times in your code, then you *will* end up with an equal number of inner classes.  If you use the pattern hundreds / thousands of times, the increased code footprint / permgen usage *could* be significant.
- What you are doing in this particular example could be expressed more simply as

  ```
  protected List<Object> extractParams(HibernateObjectColumn column, 
                                       String stringVal) {
      return Collections.singletonList("");
  }
  ```
- For cases where you have to populate the list with multiple values, a solution involving a static helper method is probably simpler.

Comment: ah, makes sense, thanks.  in this particular case I'll probably replace it with Arrays.asList("") since Collections.singletonList("") will provide an immutable list and it's possible that client code modifies the result.

Comment: Yes -  `Arrays.asList(...)` is a better solution.

Comment: @depsypher However, remember that the result of `Arrays.asList` still cannot be resized. The only thing you can do (in this instance) that `Collections.singletonList` can't is using `list.set(0, ...)`. Also, APIs are cleaner when returning immutable lists. Callers really should clone the list when they want to modify it; shallow list copies are not expensive.

Answer (score 0):

> Does declaring many identical anonymous classes waste memory in java?

Of course it does but you're not doing that in the code you posted.

Comment: He certainly is declaring one anonymous class.  I think the connotation is that he will have that code in lots of places.

Comment: @tster Exactly. He is declaring one anonyous class. Not 'many'. No connotation necessary. He is explicitly asking 'will Java create a new class declaration and store it in perm gen space for every call of this method?'. It won't.